# Excel - return value from dates

Tags: excel, date

I want to return a value based on a date of birth in a sheet full of employee data as I am forecasting generation profile over the next 5 and 10 years.

so
If the date of birth is between 01/01/1965 and 31/12/1981 I want to return 'Gen X' in the column next to the date.  Does anyone know the formula?

Comment: Just use `AND` and `>` and `<`.

Comment: thanks @BigBen can you elaborate a bit please, what would the formula be?

Comment: Dates are numbers. So you can use `<` and `>` operators on them. Can you give it a try?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

=IF(AND(R16>23743,R16<29951),"Gen X",)

23743 = Jan 1st 1965

29951 = Dec 31st 1981

to find these values, the easiest way is to type the date in mm/dd/yyyy form and then change the formatting from 'date' to 'general'

Comment: replace r16 with whatever cell your date is in

Comment: you can complete this formula by using nested if statements for the other generations

Comment: that formula returns a '0' ?

Comment: =IF(AND(K2>1/1/1965,K2<1/1/1981),"Gen X",)

Comment: are you using 23743 or 1/1/1965? 23743 works for me

Comment: I still get a 0 even with =IF(AND(L2>23743,L2<29587),"Gen X",)

Comment: Make sure that the date you are referencing in cell L2 is actually formatted as a date.  Also, are you sure that the date you are testing is between the gen x range? note that the default form for dates is mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: you could also try this  `=IF(AND(E23>DATE(1965,1,1),E23<DATE(1981,12,31)),"Gen X")`